# Google chrome extension publishing

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I have added my extension in google chrome and it got accepted. I have not published to public, since I have to do some testing. I have set its visibility to 'Unlisted' (Only people with the link can see it.) and published it.

Now the problem is whenever I send that link to any user (my friend), he complains that 'Add to chrome' button is disabled. I checked it myself I got the same problem that button is disable.

If someone knows about this issue please help. I cannot provide its link now since I wanna safeguard my product's interest.

Thank you.

Comment: Any error message you got? Could you provide the AppID?

Comment: I wonder if you're still having the issue with your extension. You can also fill a bug on [crbug.com](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list) since it sounds more like be blocked by the bug to me.

Comment: any update on this issue ? does your friend need to signIn from that link?

Comment: I filled a bug in crbug.com and it got solved later

Comment: In my case after publishing the extension, it took some time for the 'add to chrome' button to enable.